# I can't view my commits in GitHub anymore

Tags: git, github, html-lists

I just have set up a repository.

The repository is about 4k files big. I tried to add the repository over the GitHubApp but it crashed every time I tried to commit... already crashes if I click on the commit input box :D

So I decided to try it via shell. Deleted all, set it up again, added files, committed all. Seemed to work fine.

Now if I start the GitHubApp (i already pulled the repository into the app) and select the repository, it shows me my commit. If I click on the commit to see the details... it takes about 20 to 30 seconds and than this error message pops up.

> ### Failed to load files for the commit

```
An error occurred while trying to load the files for this commit.  
Try selecting another commit and then select this commit.  
If that does not work, contact support@github.com.
```

After this message showed up, no repository will show its details. It's like it's disabled or something. Even if the commit only includes one file, it won't show up anymore...

What could this be?

**Questions:**

- Why can't i view my committed changes?
- Is it normal that after committing, my app says unsynced commits?
- Does the repository must be on github or is a local repository also legitim?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a new local repo with:

- 4000+ files
- to be published on a brand new GitHub repo

You can:

```
cd /path/your/repo
git add .
git commit -m "First big commit."

git remote add origin https://YourLogin@github.com/YourLogin/yourRepo
git push -u origin/master
```

---

If it is about a GitHub repo with 4000+, you can clone it using command line first:

```
git clone https://YourLogin@github.com/YourLogin/yourRepo
```

And see if the files are downloaded that way.

---

Once everything is working in command line, you can try the GitHub app.

---

The [associated discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54935/discussion-between-dwza-and-vonc) reveals that adding too many files for a first commit could make G4W (GitHub for Windows) crash.

Comment: i did this... and i also added the repo top github.com but doesn't changes the behavior. it does the same if i just use my repo. local

Comment: @Dwza is it a local repo with many files (to be pushed to an empty repo), or a github repo with many files (to be cloned locally)?

Comment: i customizing a onlineshop. i had a local folder and i wanted to write down my changes... best way, github. so actually it's a local repo but i tried to set it online to may get rid of the problem

Comment: i published the local repo, if you mean that. the local folder contains 4k+ files. asking me about the published one ?

Comment: @Dwza yes: GitHub = published: is your GitHub repo empty or not? Does it have the 4000+ files?

Comment: @Dwza so c an you try the `git push -u origin master` in command line, and see if your files are uploaded that way?

Comment: Have you, uh, pushed your changes to it? A commit on your local repo doesn't automatically go up to the remote repository.

Comment: ok, atm its pushing it to github, ill give you a result after its finished

Comment: @Dwza ok: here '`origin`' is the name of the remote which references your GitHub repo. You can see it by typing `git remote -v` within your local repo.

Comment: so now its pushed and i can see it on github. app still don't provide me with viewing my changes. at least my history is synced now ^^

Comment: @Dwza that seems a progress!

Comment: @Dwza try now to clone the GitHub repo through the GitHub App, in another local folder, to see if that work better.

Comment: i cloned it no local folder is cloned/demoshop but how to push this into app now ?

Comment: @Dwza do you mean that your new local repo (cloned from the GitHub repo) has no file in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54935/discussion-between-dwza-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error message, but it was for an existing git repo hosted on BitBucket. I had over 4000 files locally (including build files), but enough files were ignored that I had much less than 4000 committed. The Github for Windows app has been working perfectly with BitBucket for me.

When the error message began, I tried reinstalling the Github client to no avail.

What fixed the issue for me was removing the local repo from the Github client and pulling it from the server again.